# I am a Bomber Pilot, how do I master my Aircraft?

Tags: ace-combat-assault-horizon

This achievement exists in Ace Combat Assault Horizon:

> **Bomber Master**
>
> Defeated a large number of enemies while flying a bomber.

How do I achieve this? Is this for multiplayer or single player? How many enemies do I need to defeat? What are the exact unlock conditions? So far, I was unable to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the single player campaign. Unfortunately, the description of this achievement doesn't really give you a good hint of the qualifying conditions.

To get this achievement, you need to destroy all of the hostile targets in campaign Mission 11, "Launch", during all three bombing runs in the first half of this mission. Make sure to destroy all green and red targets present.